# How to make StripLine appear over chart data points

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I have a microsoft chart control and I use a `StripLine`.
How do I make the `StripLine` appear in front of the data points. Currently the strip line is hidden behind some data. 
The chart is an area chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware `StripLine` will always be drawn behind the data points. One way to fudge this howerver would be to use a `PostPaint` event handler and draw the rectangle yourself.

inside the handler your can get drawing coordinates as follows

```
private void chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
  ChartArea a = sender as ChartArea;
  if (a != null)
  {
    Gaphics g = e.ChartGrpahics.Graphics;
    RectangleF r = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(new RectangleF(0,0,10,50)); // the rect you need
    g.FillRectangle(new Brushes.Yellow, r);
  }
}
```