# How to make stripline display in front of chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, webforms

I want to display horizontal line in my chart. So I'm using StripLine but the line did not appear in front of the chart. How can I change this?

[This is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhhnT.png)

This is my code..

> .aspx.cs

```
StripLine stripLine1 = new StripLine();
        stripLine1.StripWidth = 0;
        stripLine1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        stripLine1.BorderWidth = 4;
        stripLine1.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        stripLine1.IntervalOffset = 50;
        stripLine1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(stripLine1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make StripLine appear over chart data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473260/how-to-make-stripline-appear-over-chart-data-points)

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN documentation on strip lines: "Strip lines, or strips, are horizontal or vertical ranges that shade the background of a chart in regular or custom intervals.". It seems that strip lines are always drawn as part of the background of the chart, and as such cannot be drawn in front of data points. You could handle the `OnPainting` event of the chart, and draw a horizontal line that way

Comment: problem has been solved.. I change it using Annotation.